# What is the point of minSDK when using appcompat?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I recently started with android development. I don't understand what is the point of specifying minSDK, when I use appcompat?
In my project I've set minSDK to api 19, targetSDK to 19, compileSDK to 19, buildTools to 23.0. And Bam, Android studio automatically linked the appcompat v7-23.0.1. What is the point of setting minSDK to 19 if I can run the app even on api 7 because of the appcompat?

Comment: If you don't use any other APIs then you would still need to set minSDK to 7. If you *do* use any API's that from the regular Android framework then you will have to indicate the lowest API that can run your app. So, it all depends on which APIs you are using. Including appcompat-v7 does not automatically make your app use the APIs in that library.

Comment: @RobMeeuwisse `set minSDK to 7` Not necessarily **7**. I support API Level **8+**, so, my minSdkVersion is set to **8**. In general, set your minSdkVersion to the minimum API Level you'll support.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, that's what I meant. I actually keep an eye on the [Android dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) to see which API levels I need to support for their marketshare. Currently, that is API 16 for me, and I rely on Android Studio to warn me if I am accidentally using APIs that are not supported at that level. With my comment I intended to indicate that even if you use AppCompat-v7 you still will need to set minSDK no lower than 7. I think you are saying the same but pointing out you might put it higher if you want te rely on other APIs.

Comment: `Currently, that is API 16 for me` It's **8** for me, since I don't want to loose the `0.2% of a billion sold units`... ;) - Yes, I agree we're saying the same thing, more or less.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are still a lot of features in Android introduced on higher versions. For example, API 14 introduced a lot of new features that weren't available before (you can see [this page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html) for a list of what's new in API 14), but this is just an example. You can read further about development considerations when deciding minimum and maximum SDK versions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#considerations).

Using a higher minSDK also means you are reducing your audience (i.e. how many people can buy that app). You can see a chart showing distribution for versions of Android [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform).

To answer your question, unless there are specific features from API 19 onwards that aren't in any support libraries, there is no point in keeping it at that - I would lower it to API 14, which means that you have access to most features in Android, as well as any support libraries for any other features you want to add in your app.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of setting minSDK to 19 if I can run the app even on
>   api 7 because of the appcompat?

you can not all the time.

where appcomapt fills gap for only a lot of APIs, there are still a lot of APIs which are not supported on lower versions even by appcompat or any other support library.

check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#apilevel) for more details.